# How do i solve this JsonSerializable error right after i logged in using azure?

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I have an issue where right after logging in with azure with the whole verification thing. I'm still very new as a programmer so I'm not sure what is causing the error. Another person is using the same project but it works fine on theirs.

This is the error i got after logging in:

> During inheritance of JsonSerializable: Uncaught ErrorException:
> Return type of Microsoft\Graph\Model\Entity::jsonSerialize() should
> either be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed

The error points to class Entity implements /JsonSerializable but i am unsure of how to solve it.

```
class Entity implements \JsonSerializable
{
    protected $_propDict;
    
    function __construct($propDict = array())
    {
        if (!is_array($propDict)) {
           $propDict = array();
        }
        $this->_propDict = $propDict;
    }

    public function getProperties()
    {
        return $this->_propDict;
    }
    
    public function getId()
    {
        if (array_key_exists("id", $this->_propDict)) {
            return $this->_propDict["id"];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public function setId($val)
    {
        $this->_propDict["id"] = $val;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getODataType()
    {
        if (array_key_exists('@odata.type', $this->_propDict)) {
            return $this->_propDict["@odata.type"];
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public function setODataType($val)
    {
        $this->_propDict["@odata.type"] = $val;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        $serializableProperties = $this->getProperties();
        foreach ($serializableProperties as $property => $val) {
            if (is_a($val, "\DateTime")) {
                $serializableProperties[$property] = $val->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);
            } else if (is_a($val, "\Microsoft\Graph\Core\Enum")) {
                $serializableProperties[$property] = $val->value();
            }
        }
        return $serializableProperties;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of your code, data, or errors. This information is text. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please edit your question to include the info as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies Dyson, I am still pretty new to this. I did some changes i hope its more presentable now.

Comment: Thanks. A basic run of your code doesn't seem to produce the error - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/be561622c26b1f6ce528e77b69cad142c075dbd3 . Can you please provide a [mre] including all code & sample data which would be needed for this error to occur?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to downgrade your PHP version unless you are using some third-party components also using jsonSerialize() and they are not able to fix it.

Here is what I did to fix it:

```
public function jsonSerialize():mixed
{
    // Some snippet here
    return $your_type;
}
```

Just give jsonSerialize() a return type, or mixed works just fine.

Comment: Doesn't work with my 8.2.12. I get `...::jsonSerialize() must be an instance of mixed, array returned`. So you cannot use `mixed` as it thinks it's a specific type. I choose to use `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` instead.

Comment: @TheStoryCoder I haven't tried it out in version 8.2 yet, but adding [\ReturnTypeWillChange] also works as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Fix For The Above Issue

> Change the return type of function :  jsonSerialize()

```
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    // Your code
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an incompatibility with php version 8.1.0. I had uninstall and download php version 8.0.13. The project is working now.